# I want to use `summarise()` to calculate min, mean and max salaries for the whole group

Tags: r

[image: In the given image, I have a dataframe that contains "Salary" column. I want to clean the values like remove '£' and ',' because I want to use the values as numeric.]

I want to use `summarise()` to calculate min, mean and max salaries for the whole group. I have tried this code snippet but

```
global_stats <- salaries %>%  summarise(mean = mean(as.numeric(levels(Salary))), min = min(as.numeric(levels(Salary))), max = max(as.numeric(levels(Salary))), n = n())
```

I'm getting this:

mean: num NAN

```
Warning in min(as.numeric(levels(Salary))) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Warning in max(as.numeric(levels(Salary))) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: The first issue is that "salaries" are stored as character strings (<chr>).  You first need to parse them into numbers, before trying to run mean.

Comment: Then, you can "group_by" the "SalaryBand" before running the summarise statement.

Comment: Could you show code example please?

Answer (score 1):

The column `Salary` is not a numeric column and it has the pound sign and commas in its values. Remove them, coerce to numeric and then summarise.

The 2nd pipe groups by `SalaryBand`, the 1st does not.

```
global_stats <- salaries %>%
  mutate(Salary = gsub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", Salary),
         Salary = as.numeric(Salary)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Salary), 
            min = min(Salary), 
            max = max(Salary), 
            n = n())

global_stats_group <- salaries %>%
  mutate(Salary = gsub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", Salary),
         Salary = as.numeric(Salary)) %>%
  group_by(SalaryBand) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Salary), 
            min = min(Salary), 
            max = max(Salary), 
            n = n())
```